# Public service variables should be defined with a BehaviorSubject type

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, behaviorsubject

Is it a good idea to **make public variables on a service `BehaviorSubject` types** as a standard approach.

The idea being, that if you want to make a variable public, chances are big that you want to respond to changes of them (now or in the near future). That seems to be the case for pretty much every public variable I add on a service.

I started to change the type of some variables because I had to, and now I am starting to see this as some kind of pattern.

**An example** would be a public variable which holds the connection state. `isConnected`. When the connection of the service is broken, you want to show a popup message to the end user, and make it dissapear when the connection is restored.

**Another example:** a variable contains the UI settings of the currently logged in user. When one of these settings changes, you want to apply these settings immediately and re-render the screen layout.

Since I haven't read about this as a pattern before,
**is this strategy flawed for some reason ?** If so, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exposing a `BehaviorSubject` as public or any `Subject` which can be next'ed (is that a verb?) is in general a bad idea. This way you will partly expose the purpose of a service to the outside world, while only the service should be in charge of doing things. So best would be to use the `.asObservable()` method. This will return an `Observable` without the subject part:

```
export class ConnectionService {
  private readonly isConnected = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  readonly isConnected$ = this.isConnected.asObservable();
}
```

A component or another service can then listen to this observable, without being able to update it directly:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="!(isConnected$ | async)" class="popup">Oh no!</div>
  `
})
export class ConnectionPopupComponent {
  readonly isConnected$ = this.cs.isConnected$;

  constructor(private cs: ConnectionService) {}
}
```

When your app grows bigger, or you expect it to grow bigger in time, it might be an idea to look at state handling using ngrx or ngxs (or whatever state managing system will suit your needs)

Comment: Great improvement :-). Thank you for perfecting the pattern. - Am I correct that the `asObservable` still retains the last value of the behaviorsubject as would be the case if you listened directly to the behaviorsubject ? ('cause that's a requirement of course)

Comment: @bvdb you are correct :) I've made a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ekc93y)

Answer (score 2):

It's an often used approach to apply the [Facade-Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to a service. When using [NgRx](https://medium.com/@thomasburlesonIA/ngrx-facades-better-state-management-82a04b9a1e39) it's quite common to group complex selectors in different services. If you want to achieve fine granular access control on a `BehaviorSubject`, you can make it public as `Observable` and provide setters for explicit manipulations.

```
class Service {

   private isConnected$ = new BehaviorSubject(false)

   get isConnected(): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.isConnected$;
   }

   setConnectionState(connected: boolean) {
      this.isConnected$.next(connected);
   }

}
```